# How to get UIImage metadata from UIImagePickerController in swift ? like ".location"

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is code what i tried

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        return self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: nil)
    }
    if let asset: PHAsset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
        print("Asset: \(asset)")
        print("Creation Data \(String(describing: asset.creationDate))")
        print("Location: \(String(describing: asset.location))")
        print("burstIdentifier: \(String(describing: asset.burstIdentifier))")
        print("burstSelectionTypes: \(String(describing: asset.burstSelectionTypes))")
        print("duration: \(String(describing: asset.duration))")
        print("mediaSubtypes: \(String(describing: asset.mediaSubtypes))")
        print("mediaType: \(String(describing: asset.mediaType))")
        print("pixelHeight: \(String(describing: asset.pixelHeight))")
        print("pixelWidth: \(String(describing: asset.pixelWidth))")
        print("sourceType: \(String(describing: asset.sourceType))")
    } else {
        print("Asset: nil")
    }
    self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: image)
}
```

Note:
i also tried with PHAsset, but it's always return nil.
Also find some suggestions but that all are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the image in PHAsset first then you will get the asset object.

```
if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.getAssetAfterStoreImage(image: originalImage) { (assetInstance) in
            //asset
            print(assetInstance)
        }
    }
}

func getAssetAfterStoreImage(image:UIImage,completion:@escaping (PHAsset) -> Void){
    
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
    }) { saved, error in
        
        if saved {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
            
            // After uploading we fetch the PHAsset for most recent video and then get its current location url
            if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with:.image, options: fetchOptions).lastObject{
                completion(fetchResult)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Just required to give location permission for the Camera app
Here is a step to give permission.
Setting app -> Privacy -> Location Service(First option) -> Camera -> select option **While Using the App**

**Your code output**

```
Asset: <PHAsset: 0x114d25100> BE7D9140-3D8D-4EAC-8D1F-F97991A9E1EF/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (2448x3264), creationDate=2020-10-22 06:26:50 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 
Creation Data Optional(2020-10-22 06:26:50 +0000)
Location: Optional(<+23.043114450,+72.6401118833> +/- 0.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course 95.04) @ 01/01/01, 5:30:00 AM India Standard Time)
burstIdentifier: nil
burstSelectionTypes: PHAssetBurstSelectionType(rawValue: 0)
duration: 0.0
mediaSubtypes: PHAssetMediaSubtype(rawValue: 0)
mediaType: PHAssetMediaType
pixelHeight: 3264
pixelWidth: 2448
sourceType: PHAssetSourceType(rawValue: 1)
```

Comment: Yes @iParesh, right but we also need to set permission in app also than we can get location might be.